# What is this typescript syntax?

Tags: typescript

Stumbled upon this code:

```
const { operator } = this;
```

from https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L89

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [object destructuring](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html). This

```
const { operator, other } = this;
```

is equivalent to

```
const operator = this.operator;
const other = this.other;
```

It's borrowed from ES6, which has [the same feature](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/).

Comment: Is there any reason to not just write `const operator = this.operator;`?

Comment: Not really, and in this case I think it'd be more readable to do it the normal way. Maybe the author just wanted to play with new features!

Comment: @AlexeyVagarenko If you need to get properties from `this`, you will need to write mutiple lines about fetch. Thereforce, ES6 offers `destructuring` is easy to write in one line.